# JFileChooser vs JDialog vs FileDialog

Tags: java, jfilechooser, jdialog, filedialog

I need to know which of the 3 is best for me. My requirements are as follows in order of importance:

- Save and load files with ease.
- File type filter **during** file selection (not afterwards).
- Look and feel is **exactly** the same as the native OS L&F.

If there is a dialog that I've not mentioned that would be more ideal, please let me know.

Comment: Anything starting J is swing so is unlikely to match native OS that well. JFileChooser allows full filtering, the AWT FileDialog is likely to be better for that. JDialog is a blank dialog!!

Comment: This much I know already. What I'm really after is a solution that satisfies all 3 bullets. I just simply can't believe that java wouldn't provide such a solution that offers both familiar L&F and a decent filtering system. Is there no way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is the rest of your application written in? If you used AWT you should use [`FileDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html). If you used Swing you should use [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html). Both classes meet all of your requirements. (A [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) is simply an empty window, you can only use it to open files if you add a `Component` to it which allows you to, and `JFileChooser` already does this for you.)

Saving and loading has to be written with your own methods, both `JFileChooser` and `FileDialog` can only be used to select file(s).

Both [`FileDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#setFilenameFilter%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) and [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileFilter%28javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter%29) support file filters during selection.

`FileDialog`'s default UI is the native OS'. `JFileChooser`'s (in fact, your entire applicatin's) UI can be set to the native OS' with `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())`.

Comment: FileDialog's file filter sucks. I've tried it. Last I tried setLookAndFeel it didn't change a thing, but I'll give it a go. It may have been a personal error.

Comment: @PerryMonschau It may suck, but it's still there. You either need to call `setLookAndFeel` before creating your components or call `SwingUtilities#updateComponentTreeUI` on your highest level container, as the javadoc states.

Comment: No, see JFileChooser's inner components have the same L&F, however the layout is not native to the OS. However, the FileDialog does in fact have the native file filter system, I'm just used to a different OS.