# Is it possible to receive a callback when a FileDialog changes state in java

Tags: java, delegates

Would it be possible to receive a callback event when a FileDialog instance changes state.
Such as if the user clicks cancel, I would get a notification, which would be optional to listen to.

Just asking, because I am used to objective c, and I kinda like how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html).show* methods. You could call such a callback yourself, if needed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Handle open button action.
    if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            //This is where a real application would open the file.
            log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
        } else {
            log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
            //   ... call your cancel callback here ...
        }
   } ...
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: Cool, how can I use this with the FileDialog, instead of the JFileChooser

Comment: I'd suggest to simply switch to the `JFileChooser`, if you can use Swing Components. `JFileChooser` does basically extend the functionality of `FileDialog`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9796800/1175253

Comment: The JFileChooser doesn't seem to be native and lacks a lot of native functionallity, but I will give it a shot

Comment: You're right about that. Sorry for not directly answering your question. `FileDialog` `.getFile()` & `.getFiles()` return `null` on abort. That could be handled the same way as `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`.